# mysql: union all and sort by relevance?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT id, title, keywords, post, img, 
       NULL as device_id, null as mfgr, null as model, null as img 
       FROM blog_posts WHERE MATCH(title, desc_meta, keywords_meta, post) AGAINST('boost')
       UNION ALL
       SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, id AS device_id, mfgr, model, img, summary
       FROM device_specs WHERE MATCH(mfgr, model, summary) AGAINST('boost');
```

consider the above query, with two tables which have nothing in common. this is for the purpose of a search script only. how would I go about maintaining relevance with the two combined tables? the query above works, but in all cases, results from `blog_posts` appear before results from `device_specs`.

Comment: wrap it in subquery and just `order by`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to add the relevance to each subquery.  You can do this without a subquery:

```
SELECT id, title, keywords, post, img, 
       NULL as device_id, null as mfgr, null as model, null as img,
       MATCH(title, desc_meta, keywords_meta, post) AGAINST('boost') as relevance
FROM blog_posts
WHERE MATCH(title, desc_meta, keywords_meta, post) AGAINST('boost') > 0
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, id AS device_id, mfgr, model, img, summary,
       MATCH(mfgr, model, summary) AGAINST('boost') as relevance
FROM device_specs
WHERE MATCH(mfgr, model, summary) AGAINST('boost') > 0
ORDER BY relevance;
```